# Screen brightness issue Toshiba Portégé after 15.04 upgrade

Tags: kernel, brightness, 15.04

I have a Toshiba Portégé Z30-A-13P.

I can no longer adjust my screen brightness after upgrading Ubuntu to version 15.04 (Kernel 3.19). The screen brightness (as well as the touch-pad) didn't work properly in 14.10 either, until I updated the kernel to 3.17. After the kernel upgrade everything (except turning off the back-light of the keyboard) worked like a sunshine.

The combination <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> and <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> shows the notification image, but doesn't actually change the screen brightness. This problem always occurs. So not (like with some other folks) only after suspension or hibernation. There is no physical problem with the laptop, since it works properly in windows (dual-boot).

Any ideas for solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found this solution that works perfectly on my Toshiba Portege. http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/